# How do I insert pipes at the beginning of a line in orgmode without them being converted to tables?

Tags: org-mode

I want to draw a vertical arrow using ASCII characters, and that results in pipes being the first character on several lines.

But org-mode thinks I'm trying to create a table, and it formats it in an unintended way.

Comment: This is probably a duplicate. The usual trick is to insert a non-breaking space before the initial `|` character. You can do that in a number of ways, but the one I use is the only one I remember: `\nbsp| This is not a | table . |`. See also [Escape character](https://orgmode.org/manual/Escape-Character.html#Escape-Character) in the manual for a less intrusive option.

Comment: I couldn't find an exact duplicate, but [this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/49038/how-can-i-get-superscripts-at-the-beginning-of-a-line-in-org-mode/50621#50621) is similar and it also shows the idiom `\zwsp` for a zero-width space. In general, I prefer visible manifestations of "invisible" things, but YMMV.

Comment: You can also use Unicode for such arrows which bypasses the problem completely: `C-x 8 RET up arrow RET`.

Comment: @NickD Inserting a no-break space using the C-x 8 RET method results in a visible, colored horizontal bar being inserted, is that the normal behavior? I would prefer it to appear as a regular space. Zero width space would work I suppose but it's kinda weird that it has no width, I guess I also prefer visible manifestations

Comment: If you move the cursor off of it, can you still see it? My cursor is a blinking red rectancle, but when it's on the zwsp, it is a blinking red thin vertical line (I guess the rectangle's width goes to 0). But if I move off it, the cursor is its normal self, and I cannot see the zwsp at all.

Comment: @NickD Yep, it's there permanently, on all the lines I added it.  Different display settings, I guess. Anyhow, you gave me a fairly good idea on how to solve the issue. If you want to submit it as an answer, I would be happy to accept it.

Comment: Sorry, the above comment was for a zwsp. Yes, nbsp is shown as a colored underscore. Do C-u C-x = when you are on it, to see its properties. Not sure how to change its appearance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of options as discussed in the comments.

The basic idea is to prevent Org mode from interpreting `|` as the beginning of the table. That happens only when the `|` character is at the beginning of the line, so the trick is to `escape` it by preceding it with another character, usually some sort of a space character - see the manual section on  [Escape characters](https://orgmode.org/manual/Escape-Character.html#Escape-Character). Two that are often used are a `non-breaking space` (hereafter abbreviated `nbsp`) and a `zero-width space` (abbreviated `zwsp`). The advantage of a `zwsp` is that  it is almost invisible; its disadvantage is that it's almost invisible :-) You can only see it if you put your cursor on it (in my case, it turns from the usual rectangle to a thin vertical line). An `nbsp` is more visible, perhaps intrusively so: it is shown as an underscore `_`.

You can enter a `zwsp` as Unicode with `C-x 8 RET zero width space RET`. You can enter an `nbsp` as Unicode with `C-x 8 RET non-breaking space RET`.

In addition, Org mode allows the use of [org-entities](https://orgmode.org/org.html#Special-Symbols): these are very visible ways to insert special characters and have them treated specially for export (but you can show them as UTF-8 characters by calling the function `org-toggle-pretty-entities`). There is a predefined set of them: see the variable `org-entities` for the value - e.g. `\nbsp` is defined there as a non-breaking space, so you can say

```org
\nbsp| THis | is | not | a | table |
```

to escape the `|`. You can also add your own entities by customizing the `org-entities-user` variable, e.g. there is no entity for a zero-width space but you can define your own. In the [question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/49038/how-can-i-get-superscripts-at-the-beginning-of-a-line-in-org-mode/50621#50621) I linked to in my comment, John Kitchin shows how to do that:

```el
(add-to-list 'org-entities-user
      '("zwsp"
      "\\hspace{0pt}"       ; latex
      nil             ; not in math-mode
      "&#8203;"           ; html
      ""              ; ascii
      nil                 ; latin1 not sure what to put here
      "​"             ; utf-8
      ))
```

so you could use `\zwsp` in your file. These serve as explicit visible reminders of what you did: invisibility is not their forte :-) :

```org
\zwsp| This | is | not | a | table |
```

But as mentioned, you can always turn them into "pretty" entities: the buffer will *look* as if you are using "real" UTF-8 characters, but the file will actually contain the explicit long form of the entity.

One additional note: this escaping mechanism comes in useful anywhere where you want to avoid Org mode interpreting something based on its syntax. In this question, it's about avoiding the interpretation of `|` as the beginning of a table line; in the linked [question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/49038/how-can-i-get-superscripts-at-the-beginning-of-a-line-in-org-mode), it is about *forcing* Org mode to interpret a `^` as a superscript. In [this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/10421/how-can-i-stop-org-mode-treating-a-number-followed-by-a-full-stop-as-a-bullet-po), it's about avoiding the interpretation of `3.` as a numbered list entry if it falls at the beginning of a line. And there is [this answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/16702/14825) by Kaushal Modi about not exporting `*foo*` as bold, which also links to a discussion on the Org mode mailing list about inserting explicit Unicode characters vs using entities. Kaushal also includes another answer that deals with org-entities in a more convenient way.

Comment: *Ackchually*, if one already gets involved with customizing entities, perhaps the pipe symbol itself could be added as an entity—so it's displayed as a bar but is seen as something like `\pipe` by Org.

Comment: Yes, although that wouldn't work for all the other applications of `\nbsp`/`\zwsp` that are mentioned in the linked questions.

Answer (score 3):

If you are drawing ASCII art, you could use an `artist-mode` code block:

```
#+begin_src artist

   +-----------------------+
   |                       |
   |   Some Box            |
   |                       |
   +-----+-----------------+
         |
         |
         |  An arrow
         |
         |
         V
  +------+------+
  |             |
  | Another     |
  |     Box     |
  |             |
  +-------------+
#+end_src
```

More documentation on "literal examples" markup, of which `artist-mode` is an instance: https://orgmode.org/manual/Literal-Examples.html

Keyboard shortcuts for easily inserting them: https://orgmode.org/manual/Structure-Templates.html

Comment: `ditaa` ([here](https://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/languages/ob-doc-ditaa.html)  and [here](https://github.com/changcs/ditaa-examples)) would be another option for box-and-arrow diagrams, as would be [graphviz/dot](https://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/languages/ob-doc-dot.html)

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to using specific modes tailored to ASCII art, you could just denote a block of text as ‘preformatted’ by putting it between lines saying `#+begin_example` and `#+end_example`. Then, Org syntax won't work inside the block, so all kinds of ASCII stuff can be used boldly. Additionally, these blocks can be formatted in monospace if the rest of the file is in a proportional font.

(I'm not sure if there's a better-fitting syntax for ‘plain text’ preformatted blocks, as ‘example’ carries a semantic connotation. Personally I'm hijacking `#+begin_src` for that, but this is undocumented.)

Comment: Did some digging in the docs: "available structure types are defined in org-structure-template-alist, see the docstring for adding or changing values" (source: https://orgmode.org/manual/Structure-Templates.html). So I guess it should be possible to define our own semantic block.

Comment: @Calculemus Uuuh, I think that's just snippets called with hotkeys. There's probably no way to add block types that easily, seeing as existing ones require special handling from Org (mostly when exporting to other formats, or to highlight and run code in `src` blocks).